# How can i save value of theme set by user to retrieve it later?

Tags: android

This is what i am doing to save value of drawables:

```
 case R.id.purple:
          for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
                currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
                button1 = buttoncos = buttonmadd = R.drawable.purple;
            }
            editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
            editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
            editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
            editor.commit();
          return true;
```

Drawables here are integeral values so it was easy.How do i store values of different themes.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this, is **SharedPreferences**

Save the relevant value:

```
SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences("theme", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
shared.edit().putString("theme_name", "THEME_BLUE").commit();
```

Retrieve the saved data:

```
SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences("theme", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String theme=shared.getString("theme_name", null);
```

For more info: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: What is this Activity.MODE_PRIVATE?

Comment: MODE_PRIVATE will create the file or replace a file of the same name and make it private to your application

Comment: Just one more thing, i define these "THEME_BLUE" as integers like this public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2; in another activity does that make any difference.

Comment: First you need to understand what is happening here.Your theme name, "THEME_BLUE" is store in  Shared Preferences as theme_name. So where ever in your application you can get the saved value which is under theme_name. So if you do not update the theme_name in Shared Preferences, no harm will happen for it. you do not have to worry.

Answer (score -1):

Read this [setTheme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) in this page, it tells that you cannot use in middle of an activity or in other words, has to be done before setting any theme to your activity.